# Create a Symfony2 Survey Form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd appreciate some help/input for a problem I have at the moment. I am looking to build a survey form, which will be created from questions already stored in my database (a table with Question objects). Each of the objects has a *story* property, which is essentially the question to be asked, and a few *option* properties, which are the choices that users can pick from.

As a trial run, I created a simple survey form with only 1 question such as below. The *story* property is called from the controller to the twig template while the *option* properties are added as a 'choice' type (sanswer) in my Form class - questiontype.

```
<form action="{{ path('SurveyStudentBundle_session',{'id':question.id}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(questiontype) }}>
    {{ form_errors(questiontype) }}

        <p>{{ question.story }}</p>

        {{ form_widget(questiontype.sanswer) }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

While the current setup displays the form the way I desire it to be, the complete survey form should consist of a set of different questions and each with its own set of choices. Additionally, the submission of the form is only performed at the end of the survey page - for the entire survey form. With that in mind, I have no solutions currently on how to make this work based on my original simple setup. I tried looking around to see if i can add a "display-text" type directly into my Form class so that I can create the *story* and *option* together in the form before rendering the complete form on twig but was unsuccessful. Can somebody with related experience please share how I can work around this? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the form collection approach. 
See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

From what I see from your requirements you'll have three levels, basically will have a object (a survey) with a collection of objects (questions) each of them will have another collection of objects (answers)